# htaccess RewriteRule for profile url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /site
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f

RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&u=$3    [L]
```

I am trying to have short urls in this manner 
if someone goes to www.mysite.com/johndoe htaccess sends him/her to this link index.php?a=profile&u=johndoe
what would be the best way to do this? I did read htaccess tutorials and tried different ways and failed :/

Comment: Are all your URL's for profile links? If they are, then I can fix that rule. If not (ie. You have `about-us` and `blog` as well), then your `htaccess` methodology will not apply due to possible conflicts.

Comment: @MikeAnthony yeah there are other rules so I believe exeptions must be made

Answer (score -1):

Try inverting the condition and remove the rewrite base:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{request_filename} !-f
RewriteCond %{request_filename} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$  /index.php?a=profile&u=$1    [L]
```

This will make it so:

> if someone goes to www.mysite.com/johndoe

The "johndoe" gets matched by `^([^/]+)/?$` and backreferenced by `$1`, resulting in:

> this link index.php?a=profile&u=johndoe

Comment: remove the rewrite base? well site is located under /site folder. and pages are accessed by /pagename.

Comment: @fogsy But according to your question, your URL looks like this: `www.mysite.com/johndoe`. And also according to your question, you want it to be rewritten to `index.php?a=profile&u=johndoe`, I don't see it say `/site/index.php?a=profile&u=johndoe`.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. it needs to be /site/name. and if i move the files to / then it should be /name only ... does it make sense ?